# TLE 2505 H-bridge not working

Tags: arduino, motor, h-bridge, full-bridge, motordriver

Using a 9.4 V power supply and the [TLE 2505 H-bridge](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1769103.pdf), I ultimately want to drive a DC motor. Currently I'm debugging using a 12 kΩ resistor in place of the motor on a breadboard and using an Arduino Nano.

I have this circuit:

[image]

It utilises the Arduino Nano as the microcontroller. It has a 3.3 V logic output.

Using this I get the following output voltages:

[image]

This isn't what I expected.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: More of a gut feeling than anything else, but there is quite a bit of sensing and control built into the drive circuitry and you may be tripping the open load detection with a dummy resistance that is higher than its own internal pull-up/-down resistors (and far higher than most motors).  Try a lower-value resistor, somewhere between 360 and 1k or better yet, a small motor.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll give it a go tomorrow. I've only got very beefy 1-4A gear motors to test with at the moment.

Comment: The motor I want to use is a 0.5A (no load, test case) 6V motor.

Comment: measure across the resistor ... referencing to ground makes no sense

Comment: I've re-wired the circuit to double check, and attached the 0.5A 6-12V motor. When setting the inputs to LOW, LOW, I get a high measured resistance from the output pins, with each outputting ~0.5V to ground, or a P.D. of 0 across them.